# Code architecture: Android-specific XAML in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, architecture

New to Xamarin. I'm creating a tabbed page in the common Xamarin project with the toolbar at the bottom like so (My `MainPage.xaml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MyProject.MainPage"
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom">

    <ContentPage IconImageSource="p1.png">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Welcome to Page 1"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>

    <ContentPage IconImageSource="p2.png">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Welcome to Page 2"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content> 
    </ContentPage>

</TabbedPage>
```

And the above is working as expected. However, I would like to do the

```
<TabbedPage ... xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom">
```

in the MyProject.Android as this way I can make sure all my Android-specific work is in that project. Is it possible to achieve this using XAML (not using code behind) or otherwise what is the best practice here?

Comment: I don't think you can to this by XAML no. But all your pages are Partial classes, so you can create a class in your android project, with the same name, and partial, to make sure you set the ToolbarPlacement value at the Bottom from within your Android project

Comment: @Miiite Different projects, different assemblies, thus you can not "share" partial classes.

Comment: If the "common" project is a shared project, it might work no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do that. From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/):

> `Platform-specifics` allow you to consume functionality that's only
>   available on a specific platform, without implementing custom
>   renderers or effects.

In my understanding, it is design for user to easily use some specific platform function in **shared project**.

And the functionality of Platform-specifics has different kinds, some are for views, some are for layout, pages and etc. You can't write them all in one class.

You can also read the document about how to [create platform-specifics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/platform-specifics/)